# Mutate if multiple values occur in additional rows together

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table of bank account transactions and I want to add a column flagging any transactions which are refunds (both the initial payment and the money coming back in) but for the life of me I can't figure out how to match the rows.

Sample data:

```
transactions <- tibble(date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04")),
                       merchant = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"),
                       amount = c(10, 5, -5, 9, 10))
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date       merchant amount refund
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1 2020-01-01 A            10 FALSE 
2 2020-01-02 B             5 TRUE  
3 2020-01-02 B            -5 TRUE  
4 2020-01-03 C             9 FALSE 
5 2020-01-04 A            10 FALSE
```

At the minute I'm only looking to match payments where the refund is on the same day, but I might change it later to include refunds that occurred any day after the payment. My first thought was to use something like below but it doesn't ensure that the values all occur in the same row. I'd prefer a tidyverse answer.

```
mutate(refund = if_else(date %in% date & 
                             merchant %in% merchant & 
                             (amount*-1) %in% amount,
                        T, F))
```

Comment: While the solution to get those `refund` values is not hard, the naive logic going into it is *very* likely to produce false-positives (and possibly false-negatives). For instance, if there are two similar purchases and one is returned, which gets flagged? If two identical purchases are returned together, then neither of them will match. If you have more data available to you, then I suggest you include more logic to it, otherwise your error rate will be both unverifiable and very-not-zero.

Comment: Yes I did think of that. I figured once I got the basic matching down I can refine it myself so I left the question with minimal data

Comment: I don't understand, your mutate call is producing your desired output, no?

Comment: @MokeEire it is in this case by chance but it isn't ensuring the matches are all in the same row. There will be some cases where the date is, merchant and amount are all in the table separately but not in one row, which would give a match when I don't want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brainwave while doing something else, it's a longer process than I was envisioning but posting my working solution here for completeness.

First I added a unique ID for each row (in reality my data already has this)

```
transactions <- tibble(date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04")),
                       merchant = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"),
                       amount = c(10, 5, -5, 9, 10)) %>%
     mutate(id = seq_len(nrow(.)))
```

Split the dataframe into two, depending on if money is going out (positive value) or out (negative) of the account. For money in, I mutated the amount column to be positive values instead so they can be matched.

```
transactions_out <- transactions %>%
     filter(amount > 0)

transactions_in <- transactions %>%
     filter(amount < 0) %>%
     mutate(amount = amount*-1)
```

Use `inner_join()` to match rows with the same date, merchant and amount in both rows. Then use `pivot_longer()` and `pull()` to save the IDs of these transactions.

In my actual data I've added extra lines here to refine the matches to reduce false positives.

```
refund_ids <- inner_join(transactions_out, transactions_in,
           by = c("date", "merchant", "amount"),
           suffix = c("_out", "_in")) %>%
     pivot_longer(starts_with("id"),
                  names_to = "type",
                  values_to = "id") %>%
     pull(id)
```

Finally, I add the new refund column to the original dataframe for the IDs in `refund_ids`:

```
transactions <- transactions %>%
     mutate(refund = if_else(id %in% refund_ids, T, F))
```

Output:

```
> transactions

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  date       merchant amount    id refund
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <int> <lgl> 
1 2020-01-01 A            10     1 FALSE 
2 2020-01-02 B             5     2 TRUE  
3 2020-01-02 B            -5     3 TRUE  
4 2020-01-03 C             9     4 FALSE 
5 2020-01-04 A            10     5 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to group by the columns which identify matching transactions, in this case `date` and `merchant`.  This would remove the need for the `x %in% y` syntax you have in the `if_else`.

#### Solution

Using `case_when()` because it gives the flexibility to refine the logic down the line. `if_else` would be equivalent (or faster?) in the 2 case situation.

```
transactions %>% 
    group_by(date, merchant) %>% 
    # This logic says:
    # When the sum of the amounts DO NOT equal to 0, it is NOT a refund
    mutate(refund = case_when(sum(amount) != 0 ~ F,
                              T ~ T))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   date, merchant [4]
  date       merchant amount refund
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1 2020-01-01 A            10 FALSE 
2 2020-01-02 B             5 TRUE  
3 2020-01-02 B            -5 TRUE  
4 2020-01-03 C             9 FALSE 
5 2020-01-04 A            10 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not at my computer any more but this looks good. I'll have a play on my bigger dataset tomorrow

Comment: This works for some cases, but not if there is a third payment with the same merchant on the same day. One of the main cases I'm trying to flag is where there's a small charge made and refunded as an active card check, but if there is also an actual charge on the same day the sum isn't 0 so it isn't being flagged

Comment: Just to say, don't worry about trying to edit this, I figured out an alternative method that works more widely. Thanks for your help though!